# How can I find out what voltage a cd player requires?

Tags: capacitor, transformer

I Have a new CD player which is 120v 60hz 15Watts. It was plugged into UK voltage 240v and the transformer burnt out. I want to change the transformer to allow 240v intake but I don't know how to tell what voltage is stepped down to and it does not have any information on the transformer.
After the transformer there is a small board which has a 25 V capacitor and then a wire which connects to the main circuit board of the CD player. How would I work out what the voltage should be coming out of the transformer ??

[image: Whole board]
[![Information[2]][2]
[image: transformer and capacitor]
[image: power in]

Comment: You could try removing the transformer and applying ever increasing DC voltages after the transformer until it starts to work. It's probably either 12V or 15V. 5V and 9V are possibilities but are pretty unlikely. But you should know that other parts are probably damaged too. Before that transformer burned out it would have been applying double the voltage to everything else and those parts would have failed much faster than the transformer would.

Comment: Assuming only the power supply died then look at the other pcb. Do you see any ics with labels that would help you find datasheets to tell what voltage it would run at?

Comment: Add a photo of the opened unit.

Comment: @ DKNguygen Hello thanks for the reply, im not sure how to do that .... I have looked at the board and tried to look for any damage but cannot see any visible signs.

Comment: @ Passerby Thanks for the reply I will look into this

Comment: @HandyHowie Hello I have uploaded some photos now showing the unit opened up.

Comment: @RS01 That's a linear power supply. If you already plugged it into 240V mains instead of 120V mains, everything received double voltage already. In addition to the transformer, there might be damage to other parta of the circuit as well. You would have to know what is the intended output voltage, otherwise we can't tell if 25V capacitor voltage rating was exceeded, and also schematics would be helpful to know what other parts there might have been damaged or not.

Comment: How do you know the transformer burnt out?

Answer (score 1):

The pictures show the device can be used with batteries.

Therefore the voltage it needs can be approximated from the amount of batteries it takes.

Assuming the device is not permanently damaged already, power it up with batteries and assume the voltage of the battery pack or measure voltage with a multimeter, and you have figured out the voltage it needs.

Comment: Thank you I tried it with batteries and it turns on the voltage was 12v in total so now I just need to buy a transformer that goes from 240v to 12v. Appreciate the help